# S9 died black screen cell gone but I need to decrypt my SD card- Help!

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, encryption, windows, android-pc

My S9 black screen death, now GONE. TMobile replaced now I have a Moto G5 android. It does see the files but does not open. I have encrypted my SD card not aware I had to decrypt from my S9 but now I can't. I have copied all information from SD card to my Win 11 pc just to have safety I hope. I've been Googling for an answer but all confused on what to do...?
So many softwares to get me to buy, don't know if it will work or any other paths to do.
Really appreciate any feedback please!

Comment: If you can not access the sd-card the card was formatted as internal storage? If yes the necessary encryption key is stored within the flash memory of your phone (also encrypted by the lock screen pin/password and the gate keeper. So if the phone dies the data on the sd-card are gone.